# excluding .class file from jar maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

I had 3 maven projects A,B,C.
A is dependent on B which in-turn depends on C.
A's POM has dependency for B and B's POM has dependency for C.
I want to exclude a class file in C when building A.

How can I do this ?
I tried doing this using excludes of maven-jar-plugin, but not able to succeed.

Comment: why do you want to exclude a compiled file?

Comment: Go to your local maven repo of C You can unjar C and remove the .class file and then make jar again and place it in the same dir, use java -jar options

Answer (score 5):

Use [`maven-jar-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/)

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude><!-- package you want to exclude --></exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I want to exclude class but not package

Comment: in <exclude> tag you can input specific class to exclude. Example: com/package/Class.class

Comment: I did following
 <plugin>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>default-jar</id>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>jar</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<excludes>
 <exclude>**/net/proj/tp/schema/CardType/v1/myClass.class</exclude>
 </excludes>
</configuration>
 </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
But this did not work,I am able to see this class file in my maven dependencies

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick and easy way of doing this. If you add a JAR as a dependency to your project, the JAR will be added to the test or compile classpath(based on the scope you provide).

The `maven-dependency-plugin` provides an `unpack` goal which can be used to unpack artifacts to a specific directory.

As a work around for your problem, you can unpack artifact C into target/classes of A during build. The `unpack` goal provides a way to exclude certain file patterns (so you can exclude specific classes).

Also make sure that C JAR is not added to A's classpath(Adjust your dependencies accordingly - probably add a dependency for C of type `pom` instead of `jar`).

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html

How to exclude C jar from A without changing B

```
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <groupId>bgroupId</groupId>
        <version>bverison</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>C</artifactId>
                <groupId>cgroupId</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>C</artifactId>
        <groupId>cgroupId</groupId>
        <version>cverison</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Now you can use the dependency plugin to unpack the C JAR appropriately(excluding certain files)

Comment: Also make sure that C JAR is not added to A's classpath(Adjust your dependencies accordingly - probably add a dependency for C of type pom instead of jar).

-- I can't do this because, C is not directly dependent on A, so it's dependency is not mentioned in POM of A, but POM of B. If I make changes to this B's POM then this is going to effect other projects which are dependent on C

Comment: @SpandanaVaddi - you don't have to make changes to the POM of B, you can get this sorted by changing A's pom file(updated the answer with some hints). But as I mentioned in the original answer, there is no clean way of doing what you are trying to do. Is there any specific reason why you are trying to exclude certain classes from the classpath?

Comment: @SpandanaVaddi -also wondering why you can't just update C's pom file so that the specific class is not packaged into C.jar?

Comment: We have same class with same class path in two different projects.
So, we want to exclude one of the class which we don't need