# How to run a main class from test sources with exec maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven

I have the following pom.xml configuration for exec maven plugin but it works only if the main class is in src/main/java, not if it's in src/test/java. I don't want this main class to end up in the distribution/release.

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>myexec</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>java</executable>
              <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
              <arguments>
                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                <classpath/>
                <argument>com.mypackage.SomeMainClass</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

The problem here is I am trying to run a class before it has been compiled (it gets compiled together with the test sources, after the generate-test-sources step). `com.mypackage.SomeMainClass` generates test sources *TestCase.java to be compiled and run.

So what could I do if I don't want the main class to end up in the released jar? I'd rather not develop a maven plugin just for this.

Comment: Why do you need that main class? Sounds like creating a test?

Comment: Yes but my question is more general. I edited the class name.

Comment: Ok, so the problem here is you are trying to run a class before it has been compiled (it gets compiled together with the test sources, after the generate-test-sources step). I think this question could be more precise but doesn't deserve the downvotes IMO.

Comment: If you are trying to run tests it's much better to create test which means create a class `XYZTest.java` which can be run automatically via surefire-plugin without using exec-maven-plugin....

Comment: @khmarbaise I think OP is trying to generate test sources, judging by the phase they chose to run in.

Comment: @kutschkem exactly yes

Comment: @khmarbaise I heard your suggestion to develop a maven plugin instead but I'd rather not do it as it is very specific for the need of this project (the released plugin would not be reusable in other projects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest solution is probably to treat this class as its own external executable and thus build it as a separate module. That would involve turning the project into a Maven multi-module project if it isn't one already.

https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-plugin-dependencies.html

The quick and dirty solution however... Maven allows you to set exclusions. If you don't want something to end up in the release jar, filter it out. I.E. :

[excluding .class file from jar maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240913/excluding-class-file-from-jar-maven-dependency)